# yii2 gii crud db relation(one to many)

Tags: php, yii2

gii generated models successfully (with relations) :

```
/**
 * @return \yii\db\ActiveQuery
 */
public function getClient()
{
    return $this->hasOne(Client::className(), ['id' => 'client_id']);
}
```

but when i generated crud, in client filed just input text field.
Help me please, where is problem?

Comment: As said by robsch, that's the default behavior, you may have a look at my gii-generator extension, which renders also relations: https://github.com/schmunk42/yii2-giiant

Comment: @schmunk Indeed an interesting extension! But I think beginners have no idea what is it all about.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's correct. In your _form.php file you have to define a dropdown box if the user should choose a client:

```php
<?= $form->field($model, 'client')->dropDownList($clients) ?>
```

and in controller actions create/update you have to provide the $clients:

```php
return $this->render('create', [  // or: return $this->render('update', [
    'model'    => $model,
    'clients' => ArrayHelper::map(Client::find()->all(), 'id', 'name'),
]);
```

Don't forget to pass them in the view files for create.php and update.php to the _form.php file:

```php
<?= $this->render('_form', [
    'model' => $model,
    'clients' => $clients, // <-- added
]) ?>
```

In other views where you just want to show client you may use this:

```php
echo $model->client->name; //or something different
```